# Post Instagram Stories using selenium/chromedriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, instagram, bots

I want to create a bot that takes in a folder path and posts all of its img contents to a instagram users story using python and chromedriver (I already have a lot of other functionalities working using this set up so I would prefer to solve this issue using these tools). If anyone has created or found something similar to what I'm describing please comment the link.

I have tried using mobile-emulation mode for chromedriver with some success. I was able to get to the file selection screen, but when I returned to instagram it was no longer doing mobile emulation and locked the UI (it was asking to rotate the device). I included the options that I have currently selected for the webdriver that I'm using. I also included the def that I use to upload a file to the story.

```py
    def __init__ (self, username, password, actionstring, inspoaccounts, 
    inspohashtags) :
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.actionString = str(actionstring)
        self.inspoAccounts = (str(inspoaccounts).split('|', 30))
        self.inspoHashtags = (str(inspohashtags).split('|', 30))
        cOptions = Options()
        cOptions.add_argument("--incognito")
        cOptions.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        cOptions.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166"')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="venv/Lib/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe", options=cOptions)
        self.driver.delete_all_cookies()
```

```py
    def uploadStory(self, path):
        path = self.cleanPath(path)
        actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            '#react-root > section > main > section > div.zGtbP > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > button')

        #THIS IS WHERE IT ASKS ME TO ROTATE MY DEVICE

        actions.move_to_element(element)
        actions.click()
        actions.perform()
        time.sleep(random.randint(3, 6))
        autoit.win_activate("Open")
        time.sleep(random.randint(4, 6))
        autoit.control_send("Open", "Edit1", path)
        time.sleep(random.randint(3, 7))
        autoit.control_send("Open", "Edit1", "{ENTER}")
        time.sleep(random.randint(3, 6))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/section/footer/div/div/button").click()
```

If anyone has any ideas or any projects feel free to comment. There are no wrong answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload a story with https://github.com/instagrambot/instapy-cli . It does the basic job with no tagging, hashtags, etc:

```
from instapy_cli import client
with client(user, passw) as cli:
    result = cli.upload(img_path, story=True)
```

Other possibilities might involve:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 

driver.set_window_size(width, height)
```

,

```
chrome_options = Options()
useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Mobile Safari/537.36"
chrome_options.add_argument(f"user-agent={useragent}")
```

,

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", {"deviceName":"Galaxy S5"}) #or whatever
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: I tried all of those options with no success. Please let me know if you get anything to work!

Comment: The Toggle Device Toolbar in Chrome Dev Tools makes it work, but I couldn't reproduce it with the above nor reach the button. Reaching the button should be possible with .send_keys(ctrl, shift, m) but for some reason it isn't working

Comment: I just tried it with instapy_cli and it worked, THANKS!

Comment: No prob. Would you choose this as the accepted response? It's my first :D

Comment: https://github.com/instagrambot/instapy-cli  doesn't work anymore because IG changes the APIs. I have the same issue with selenium and .send_keys(ctrl, shift, m) to access Toggle Device Toolbar doesn't work. Does anybody know how to solve this issue to post Stories with Python and Selenium?

Comment: you can accomplish it with selenium. I've made a script to upload, you can't tag but it does the basic job